# what is the usage of 'super_process_instance_id_' and 'parent_task_id_'?

Tags: activiti

I'm using activiti 6 and process has sub processes. So i create a xml using subProcess  element. I thought activiti generate a another proc_incinst id for each sub processes. Is there way to combine two process using super_process_instance_id_ ?

Comment: you can get a `superExecutionID` corresponding to both of your process and sub-process.

Comment: @AbbasKararawala How can i get it or save it using activiti methods? or solud I save generate it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get `DelegateExecution` in your script or java service, from Activiti 6.0 it has method for getting the root process instance id i.e. the process instance id of the process calling other sub-processes with the current execution - see [docs](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/6.latest/org/activiti/engine/delegate/delegateexecution#getRootProcessInstanceId())

a java impl would look like

```
// your class
protected void execImpl(DelegateExecution execution){
    System.out.println("root process instance id: " + execution.getRootProcessInstanceId());
}
```

calling the above service from the parent process will return the process instance id of itself, calling it from the subprocess will still return process instance id of the parent process.